# How do I install a javascript dependency in Nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js

I understand that for component dependencies we should avoid `import` in components and use plugins instead.

Example of plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Splide, SplideSlide } from '@splidejs/vue-splide';
Vue.component('splide-slide', SplideSlide)
Vue.component('splide', Splide)
```

Now the question is, how do I load a javascript library in a nuxt project?

I have tried like this but does not work:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Video from '@splidejs/splide-extension-video';

Vue.use(Video)
```

Answer (score -3):

The right way is using head property and append the script source directly.

More info here: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-load-third-party-scripts-in-nuxt-js/